# Constraint a scala type such that I would never need to check for null?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def myMethod(dog: Dog) = {
   require (dog != null) // is it possible to already constraint it in the `Dog` type?
}
```

Is there a way to construct `Dog` such that it would be an `ADT` which would never be able to accept a `null` thus eliminate any null check? (I don't want an `Option` here, otherwise all my code would turn to have `Option` based, I want to already constraint the `Dog` class such that `null` is never possible, this is why `type system` is for to allow me to specify constraints in my program).

Comment: How would you assure at runtime you won't pass a null? What would be a behaviour of this soulution if you eventually pass null? Runtime exception that crashes your application? You could use `Try` and put whole block of code inside. Afterthat only thing to do is register callbacks. But type-based solution due to my knowledge does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an attempt to provide such functionality (example I'm running in 2.10.4):

```
class A extends NotNull
defined class A

val x: A = null
// <console>:8: error: type mismatch;
// found   : Null(null)
// required: A
//       val x: A = null
                  ^
```

Though it was never complete and [eventually got deprecated](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7247). As for the time of writing, I don't think it's possible to construct ones hierarchy in a way that prevent you from nulls, [without additional nullity checking analysis](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7247?focusedCommentId=69749&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-69749).

Check out comments in relevant ticket for an insight

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, generally, because Java ruins everything. If you have a Java method that returns Dog, that could give you a null no matter what language/type features you add to Scala. That null could then be passed around, even in Scala code, and end up being passed to myMethod.

So you can't have non-null types in Scala without losing the interoperability property that Scala objects are Java objects (at least for the type in question).

Unfortunately inheritance makes it very difficult for the computer to know in the general case whether a method could be passed an object that originated from Java - unless everything is final/sealed, you can always subclass a class that handled the object at some point, and override the Dog-returning method. So it requires hairy full-program analysis to figure out the concrete types of everything (and remember, which concrete types are used can depend on runtime input!) *just* to establish that a given case could not involve Java code.

Comment: It's not only java -- [scala has some initialization warts](http://engineering.tapad.com/blog/2012/11/here-there-be-dragons-dangers-of-initialization-order-in-scala/), especially if you bake a set of traits. You can have interoperability with java, in some sense, of course -- by treating everything that comes from java unsafe. In fact, [this is what Kotlin does](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Kotlin/Null-safety), though you may argue that this is `Option` on steroids, which has been promoted into the core language.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yep, that looks 100% equivalent to having `Option` and removing null from the language. In the sense that the "null Dog" value is a member of a different *type* than `Dog`, and it isn't valid to pass a `Dog?` to something expecting `Dog`. Consequently, if all stuff that comes from Java is treated as unsafe, then it would have to be impossible to override a method returning `Dog` with Java code; the Java code would have to return `Dog?`. Given that page lists "external Java code" as a remaining cause of NPEs, I'd guess that Kotlin allows nulls from Java in non-nullable types.